# redirecting a webpage from site A to site B without changing url

Tags: url, redirect, address-bar

I would like to redirect the user when he/she clicks on a link () to b.com when the user is in a.com without displaying the change in the browser's address bar.

How would I do this? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: It's naughty but I think i remember back in the day seeing someone using a hidden frame to achieve this? Like I say, naughty, so I'l leave it up to you or someone else to work out how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You'd either have your web server proxy the other site, using something like [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html), or some some [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) setup. Or, you have a page with a single iframe on it that displays the other site.

Comment: can't go in the above options

Comment: @Technocrat: You don't really have any options other than SpoonMeiser's list.